# Shading artifacts after baking normal map

Tags: shaders, baking, normal-map, artifacts

I tried baking a normal map from high poly to low poly mesh. The high poly is basically just the low poly with beveled edges and proper smoothing. I'm absolute beginner when it comes UV unwraping and baking, yet I still think I've done an okay job with unwrapping. There is no stretching, I thought it will come up nicely. I even tried to increase the margin to something like *0.003* to give each island a "room to breathe".

[image]

I triangulated the low poly model, set the following settings for baking and baked each part of the mesh by one, after the first bake I deselected the *Clear Image* option.

[image]

I baked into *4096x4096* *32bit* image without *alpha*, set to *non-color*. This is how the normal map looks like after the bake downsized to 1024x1024 (in Blender I used the size of 4096x4096, I just had to downsize it so I can post it here).

[image]

I can see a few green areas, which apparently is the reason behind my problem. I have no idea how to fix it, though. I tried to use the cage, but either I didn't understand it or it doesn't work too.

This is what my high-poly mesh look like. I know it's hard to see the details from the image, but see for yourself by looking at the file I provided at the end of this post if you're interested in helping me.

[image]

And this is my low-poly mesh with the normal map and the shading artifacts I'm referring to. I also used a red diffuse color so the artifacts are visible a bit more.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Some of the edges look okay, some have these shading issues. My goal, though, is to bake this inside substance painter, however it gives me the same errors so I assume there's a problem with my mesh, and not with the settings or my lack of skills when it comes to baking/unwrapping.

I've spent too much time trying to come up with a solution, but I was unable to. So I'd be more than grateful if any nice (.. or bored) soul decides to help me, thanks a lot!

Here is the file with the unwrapped low-poly and rough high-poly meshes, nothing is triangulated nor baked, so that you can start fresh. Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The green areas are where the baking rays have shot off the surface and penetrated an adjacent surface—which makes sense considering the divets in the lid. Try lowering your ray distance in your bake settings so they won’t shoot out so far and hit something else by mistake.

Comment: This didn't help. I tried to go gradually from 0.1 to 0.0001, but there was no difference. The shading artifacts are still here.